# How to migrate data from one snowflake instance to another, best performance option?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am brand new to Snowflake, and would like to move few databases from a Snowflake instance in USWEST to snowflake instance in USEAST.

What is the best way to do this cost and performance wise?

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always replicate the data from USWEST to USEAST.  That's probably the easiest way, especially if you are only concerned with the data.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/database-replication-failover.html

If that method isn't something you want to explore, then exporting files to S3 and then re-importing them in USEAST account is likely your 2nd best option.